# How Online Payment Gateways Works nowadays?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, onlinebanking

Can you tell be the basic architecture of a online payment gateway.

But it supposed to be for credit card holder only, i.e how payment gateways responded to credit card? How gateways recognize the credit card issuer?

Comment: I'm sufficiently confused. With regards to how the gateway knows the issuer of the card, e.g. AMEX, Visa, Mastercard, it is by the number itself which has an issuer-specific prefix. Beyond that, you will need to clarify your question.

Comment: While this question may be very general, i would vote to keep it open as someone may be able to provide a good answer on the steps or flow involved.

Comment: Could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647430/building-a-complete-online-payment-gateway-like-paypal if its related to development. I could describe the architecture in more general terms, but I suspect it would get closed as not programming related :(

Comment: @paulG please explain this issue.

Answer (score 3):

There are three basic elements of any payment gateway. Secure storage of credit card number as per the PCI DSS, AUTH and Settlement (capture).

1. Have a service to securely store the card number and return a token or a hash as handle for credit card.
2. You need rule engine or a service to Identify the CARD TYPE (VISA, MC, DISC, AMEX etc.) from BIN .
3. An ESB or content based router to send the request to appropriate acquirer based on CARD TYPE or BIN.
4. A service with high SLA to perform a real-time AUTH
5. A service or batch job for settlement (CAPTURE)