# What is the best way to use ionic 3 to create a library that can be imported in a mobile app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm trying to create a payment SDK library with ionic 3, that can be integrated into an android or ios app.
I've got the app working on ionic, but how do I make it import ready for mobile apps to use?

To give more clarity. I have a microservice already running and native android and ios library accessible via maven for android. I want to replace this with a hybrid version(ionic).

Is it possible to make an ionic library available on maven?

Answer (score 0):

Payment Gateway SDK allows developers to manage the communication and compliance elements for secure integration and transaction processing. You can't create a Payment Gateway with Ionic.
What you need to do is that:

- isolate your payment process into a library (API or Microservice)
- create a library for Ionic (in TypeScript) or for other platforms (Kotlin, Swift)
  Create a Payment Gateway is complex. Document yourself before starting. You can start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647430/building-a-complete-online-payment-gateway-like-paypal).

Comment: Thanks Junior for the response. I already have a Microservice for this. I'm looking to create one library (using ionic) that can be used across platforms(ios, android, windows), to communicate with this microservice and load a webview